# H5P: Unknown environment 'table'

Tags: h5p

I try to add a table in my H5P exercise using latex. As mentioned here I am using the *'$$'* notation in front of the latex code but I also tried the *'( ... )'* notation. However, I always get the following error:

> Unknown environment 'table'

This is the code I am adding to the exercise body:

```
Question 1

\( f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos \left( \frac{2 n \pi x}{\nu} - \alpha_n \right) \)

$$\begin{table}[] \begin{tabular}{|l|c|} 1 & 2 \end{tabular} \end{table} \)$$
```

The first part (the function) is working fine and shown correctly. However, for the table I just get the error.

Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H5P.MathDisplay library is based on MathJax, and MathJax only implements the macros used for math layout, not text layout. There's no support for commands such as `\begin{table}` or `\begin{tabular}` or `\begin{center}`.

Without [amending the MathJax configuration](https://h5p.org/mathematical-expressions), you could use an array environment.

```
\[
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{Set} & \text{Operation} & \text{Identity} \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{Z} & + & 0 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{Q} & + & 0 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{R} & + & 0 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{Z} & \times & 1 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{Q} & \times & 1 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{R} & \times & 1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]
```